# Why do Dojo DOM functions end up with different results on IE?

Tags: javascript, dojo, cross-browser

In short, a script using the Dojo framework ends up with different results on IE.

Here is a sample page demonstrating the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.connect(document.body, "onload", function () {

    var d = dojo.query("div");
    var s = dojo.query("span");
    dojo.empty(d[0]);
    dojo.create("span", {innerHTML: s[0].innerHTML}, d[0]);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><span>foobar</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>Don't bother trying it over at jsFiddle, this particular case does not reproduce over there.</sub>

Sample should output `foobar` but on IE it does not.

Why does this happen and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging and debugging I managed to track the issue down to the internals of Dojo:

```
397.empty = has("ie") ? function(node) {
    node = dom.byId(node);
    for (var c; c = node.lastChild; ) {
        _397.destroy(c);
    }
} : function(node) {
    dom.byId(node).innerHTML = "";
};

_397.destroy = function destroy(node) {
    node = dom.byId(node);
    try {
        var doc = node.ownerDocument;
        if (!_3a2 || _3a3 != doc) {
            _3a2 = doc.createElement("div");
            _3a3 = doc;
        }
        _3a2.appendChild(node.parentNode ? node.parentNode.removeChild(node) : node);
        _3a2.innerHTML = "";
    } catch (e) {
    }
};
```

As can be seen from above code, IE gets a special case but unfortunately it is not functionally equivalent - things end up different.

Not sure if this is a bug but certainly a feature of questionable merit. A workaround is to run `dojo.clone()` on `innerHTML` before invoking `dojo.empty()`:

```
var d = dojo.query("div");
var s = dojo.query("span");
var i = dojo.clone(s[0].innerHTML);
dojo.empty(d[0]);
dojo.create("span", {innerHTML: i}, d[0]);
```